# Are there any verses containing prescriptions or advisements to build up muscular strength?

Tags: shloka, body, ayurveda, health

As in instructions to maintain bodily strength, to be able to fight, overall just emphasizing physical strength?

Comment: Vedas are there for your spiritual health and not for your material body.

Comment: @DarkKnight - wrong. Vedas are there for everything. But the ones that you commonly know about are the spiritual aspects because the material aspects are either lost or hidden in time.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to StackExchange!

This text from the atharvaveda saMhitA is one that was traditionally used for bodily strength

19.60:

> vA~N ma Asan nasoH prANash chakShur akShNoH shrotraM karNayoH, apalitAH keshA ashoNA dantA bahu bAhvor balam. Urvor ojo ja~Nghayor javaH pAdayoH, pratiShThA ariShTAni me sarvAtmAnibhRRiShTaH.
>
> Speech in my mouth, breath in my nostrils, sight in my eyes, hearing in my ears, my hair not gray, my teeth not broken, much strength in my arms. Force in my thighs, speed in my calves, firm standing in my feet, all things of mine uninjured, myself not down-fallen.

[You can listen to it here.](http://vedicheritage.gov.in/samhitas/atharvaveda-samhitas/shaunaka-samhita/kanda-19-sukta-060/)